# Padding not applied on html tags in angular material

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, angular-material

I am trying to apply some spaces after a `h1` tag in my angular application. I am using angular material. The CSS code is

```
.h1{
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;   /* 10px left and right padding*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The html code is

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="navbar">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <h1>MoD</h1>
        <div>
            <a mat-button [routerLink]="'/home'"> Home </a>
            <a mat-button [routerLink]="'/aboutUs'"> About Us </a>
            <a mat-button [routerLink]="'/contacts'"> Contacts </a>       
        </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

I cannot seem to understand why the `padding-right` makes no difference. The button is always close to the title. I am new to angular material, any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here h1 is a element not a class so remove . ( dot ) infront of h1 in your css

```
Right Way:

<h1> .... </h1>

h1{
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

Wrong Way:

<h1> .... </h1>

.h1{
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: oh...you're right.. how did i miss that..